# MySQL: Create a trigger keeps giving me syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I've been trying to create a trigger from java and it just won't work.

```
String trigger = String.format("CREATE TRIGGER `%s` AFTER %s ON %s BEGIN INSERT INTO `ndb_log` (`table_name`, `action`, `time`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) END;",
            name, this.event.toUppercase(), this.table, this.table, this.event.toLowercase());

CREATE TRIGGER `onnc_censorINSERT` AFTER INSERT ON nc_censor BEGIN INSERT INTO `ndb_log` (`table_name`, `action`, `time`) VALUES ('nc_censor', 'insert', UNIX_TIMESTAMP()); END;
```

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN   INSERT INTO `ndb_log` (`table_name`, `action`, `time`) VALUES ('nc_censor' at line 1

I am not running this in phpMyAdmin, a server console or anything like that. I need to run it from java in a `String`. I call `this.mysql.update(trigger);` in my class which "basically" runs it.

I have tried running the create trigger string in ssh mysql, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: (1) you're missing the FOR EACH ROW clause of the trigger declaration; (2) you don't need the BEGIN and the END, because your trigger executes just one statement. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `onnc_censorINSERT` AFTER INSERT ON nc_censor FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `ndb_log` (`table_name`, `action`, `time`) VALUES ('nc_censor', 'insert', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: I only want to insert 1 record, no matter how many rows are inserted, so how can I get it to do that?

Comment: It seems like a trigger is not appropriate, then. A trigger is executed for every row affected by the operation; there is no way to change this behavior. Therefore, you'd be better off running an INSERT command via your frontend code at the beginning or end of your batch of INSERTs.